# Stop working google map in fragment android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am new in google map for android. I just tried simple google map in Fragment and i got stop working. Maybe this Question same with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583522/android-google-maps-in-fragment) but i have not found good answer. I hope someone can help me.
This java code

```
public class MenujuStasiun extends Fragment {

    public MenujuStasiun() {
    }

    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mstasiun, container, false);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rootView;
        }

    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps",      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

}
```

this mstasiun.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the logcat error

```
12-27 23:36:28.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1310): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
    12-27 23:36:28.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
    12-27 23:36:28.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    12-27 23:36:28.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    12-27 23:36:28.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    12-27 23:36:28.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at com.tugasbesar.medantrain.MenujuStasiun.onCreateView(MenujuStasiun.java:21)
    12-27 23:36:28.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
    12-27 23:36:28.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4777)
    12-27 23:36:28.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
```

Comment: And what is the error? Logcat trace?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768934/android-binary-xml-file-line-9-error-inflating-class-fragment/20769002#20769002

Comment: @gian1200 see my last edit

Comment: @chintankhetiya i have try the answer in this link. SupportMapFragment error

Comment: just go through http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Comment: the code above is from that link. but it for Activity. i want to use for Fragment

Comment: why are you calling your method inside `onResume`? can you post your mstasiun.xml too?

Comment: @gian1200 look at my last edit. I have try delete method onResume but it still stop working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's only your xml, then you don't really need that RelativeLayout. 
You don't really need `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"` if you use `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"`. What you are missing is `xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Summarizing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

You are using a real device to test, right? You need to configure your emulator in order to make it work with Google Play Services.

Comment: I am not using real device now. I just use avd emulator. Btw how to configure Google Play Services in my emulator ?

Comment: Starting from Android 4.2.2, it is easier to configure. Just need to have an emulator running "Google API 4.2.2" or higher (not Android 4.2.2). More info here: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html